# Ad-Hoc and Enterprise signed apps crashing on launch screen in iOS 13.3.1

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ad-hoc-distribution, code-signing-certificate, enterprise-distribution

As i updated my `iPhone XS Max` from `13.3` to `13.3.1` I'm getting crash on every `Same Signed Apps` and `Self-signed Apps`.

So I thought it is some problem with their certificate, then I tested those apps using an `iPhone X` running `iOS 13.3`.
The result was fine and apps worked well, as I found out the problem was not certificate but a change in Apple's mechanism for `iOS 13.3.1` that does this problem.

And the enterprise signed apps crashes are not because of revoke.
Certificates were fine and **`I did not getting: Unable to Verify App`**

### What i did and was not helpful for me:

- Opening the app again
- Free UP RAM
- Shutdown and start again
- Force Restart
- Reset all settings

Answer (score 0):

### Solution for Self-signed apps

I could solve the problem for `Self-signed Apps` and that was because of expiration of `ad-hoc` distribution expiration days.

Each iOS app that you sign with `Apple developer program` is available for **365 Days** from the time you sign and install that.

---

### Why this happend?

I thought it occurred because i changed my date and time settings on my device from `2020` to `2022` for a test purpose.
This action expired my sign and I was getting crash on launch screen. That was because apple interacting with device time for checking validation of sign.

---

### How to fix this?

I fixed the apps by signing them again with same certificate.
Without removing them.